# ViewFlipper in AppWidgets and Don't keep activities

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-appwidget

I am trying to implement a Appwidget using view flipper. I declared two views in my view flipper and everything working fine. Now from developer options select "Don't keep activities option" and come back to home screen. You will find appwidget with viewflipper is hang.

Remove appwidget from screen and resinstall. It will start workin normally till you are on home screen. Launching any activity will result in same problem. Your appwidget stop working.

From the logs there are nothing coming to your appwidget provider. Every time we launch any activity Home screen activity get killed.

This problem happens every time with ViewFlipper in particular.

I am really frustrated, with every new release Google adding more instability. Android should decide either handle activity cycle OR simply handle it like iOS.

If any body able to get around this problem with View flippers on Appwidget please enlighten me. Or If anyone think better not use viewflipper on appwidget , please share.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? My app widgets are unclickable when the "Don't keep activities" checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! this is my problem, I thought I just wasn't handling low memory situations with the appwidget id's correctly

this app uses viewflippers on a widget https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.ccltd.maplights.nyc.freemium&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvLmNjbHRkLm1hcGxpZ2h0cy5ueWMuZnJlZW1pdW0iXQ..

what I did increase the widget update time, which is now 30 minutes. for my particular application this is adequate. Basically it the viewflippers and pendingintents will hang after android deprioritizes it (won't even be able to get a response after a click), but after the widget updates it will be working again.

or so I think, more testing is needed! but its good to know that its not only my handling of appwidget ids in low memory situations, but possibly a glitch